# How do I connect VB.Net Winforms App to ServiceM8

Tags: vb.net, winforms

It appears that I am able to get the temp-token, but when I try to convert to a permanent token I get "BAD REQUEST". Any help would be appreciated.
Code is hooked to WebBrowser1.Navigated

```
Dim strTempToken As String = ""
    If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString.ToUpper.StartsWith("HTTPS://GO.SERVICEM8.COM/DASHBOARD?&S_AUTH=") Then
        Try
            Dim arrURL As Array = Split(WebBrowser1.Url.ToString, "&")
            strTempToken = arrURL(1).ToString.Replace("s_auth=", "")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Fail-1." & ex.Message)
        End Try
        If strTempToken.Length > 0 Then
            Try
                Dim hc As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient
                Dim req As New System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, "https://www.servicem8.com/oauth/access_token")


                req.Headers.Add("client_id", strClientID)
                req.Headers.Add("client_secret", strClientSecret)
                req.Headers.Add("code", strTempToken) '

                Dim res As System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = Await hc.SendAsync(req)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(strKeyPath & "servicem8-perm-key.txt", res.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString, False)
                MessageBox.Show("Success")
                WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Fail-2." & ex.Message)
            End Try

        End If
    End If
```